# How to find the nearest color in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with an incrementing  color-number, and a corresponding HTML-hex value. (hex-value without #)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T_SYS_ColorToHex
(
     COL_Number int NOT NULL 
    ,COL_Hex varchar(6) NULL 
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_T_SYS_ColorToHex PRIMARY KEY (COL_Number)
);
```

Now I am given a color,

e.g. `'007FFF'`, and need to find the nearest color in the table (T_SYS_ColorToHex).

How do I do this ?

Comment: why do you have a database dedicated to colours that doesn't have every possible value?

Comment: Which is nearest? `017FFF` or `007FFE`?

Comment: @SaggingRufus: Yes, we have a 3rd party application that uses integers and 256 colors.

Comment: You'll need to have solid rules about what color is 'closest' / nearest for this to work.  Is it 'nearest' as far as changes to the Red green blue value for each color?  Is is nearest as far as which hex value is closest (which is closest to 007FFF, 107FFF 017FFF 007FFE 007EFF etc...?).  Simplified example, if you are given purple, is blue or red closest?

Comment: @Twelfth: Just assume all primary colors are all equally important, so they all have the same weight. That means euclidean metric.

Comment: @StefanSteiger - Exactly ;) and if that's true, then every color is going to have up to 6 equal answers (purple could have blue/red/brown/light purple/darker purple all appearing an equivalent distance apart) and he will need some 'ordering' logic to pick out one answer, unless he is OK with having up to 6 colors as 'nearest'.  Your answer is great, the only thing he will need to consider is 'order by dist' could have multiple values with equal dist and he will need some logic to determine which of the multiple values to use or leave it somewhat random based on how SQL default orders it.

Comment: @Twelfth: Agreed, now he would have to add further logic to determine the best color. But I guess an arbitrary record is enough when converting from 16 million colors to 256 - unlikely you will have 2 exactly "equally-good" matching colors in that case anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to define the difference, you need to first define a metric. 
Since it's RGB, it's in 3d-space, so you could simply use the Euclidean norm/distance

**sqrt( (r<sub>1</sub> - r<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (g<sub>1</sub> - g<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (b<sub>1</sub> - b<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> )**

You need to extract every component (R,G,B) and convert it to a number

```
,CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, SUBSTRING(COL_Hex, 1, 2), 2)) AS R
,CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, SUBSTRING(COL_Hex, 3, 2), 2)) AS G
,CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, SUBSTRING(COL_Hex, 5, 2), 2)) AS B
```

Also, you're just doing a comparison, so you don't need the effective values, just the relative ones. So you can skip computing the square-root.

Then you just need to get the first tuple when ordering ascending by distance.

So that means, like this:

```
SELECT 
     COL_Number 
    ,COL_Hex 

    ,R2
    ,G2 
    ,B2 

    ,R1
    ,G1 
    ,B1 

    -- Comparisons are relative - SQRT not necessary 
    ,--SQRT( 
        POWER((r1 - r2), 2) + POWER((g1 - g2), 2) + POWER((b1 - b2), 2) 
    --) 
    AS dist 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
         COL_Number
        ,COL_Hex
        ,CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, SUBSTRING(COL_Hex, 1, 2), 2)) AS R2
        ,CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, SUBSTRING(COL_Hex, 3, 2), 2)) AS G2
        ,CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, SUBSTRING(COL_Hex, 5, 2), 2)) AS B2


        ,CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, SUBSTRING(ColorToEvaluate, 1, 2), 2)) AS R1 
        ,CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, SUBSTRING(ColorToEvaluate, 3, 2), 2)) AS G1 
        ,CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, SUBSTRING(ColorToEvaluate, 5, 2), 2)) AS B1 
    FROM T_SYS_ColorToHex 

    CROSS JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 'FF00FF' AS ColorToEvaluate 
    ) AS tParam 

) AS t  

ORDER BY dist 

OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```